# How to create a dynamic object in C#

Tags: c#

I use this to create a dynamic object in Visual Basic before sending it as an JSON

```
Dim my_object = New With { _
   .Name = String.Empry, _
   .Telephone = String.Empry, _
   .ID = String.Empry
}
```

How can this be done in C#?

Comment: This is not a dynamic object, this is an anonymous type.

Answer (score 12):

That is an anonymous Type.

```
var my_object = new
{
    Name = string.Empty,
    Telephone = string.Empty,
    ID = string.Empty
};
```

However, note that Stackoverflow is not a translation service normally.

Use this site instead: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/

Answer (score 9):

If you mean creating an instance of an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397696.aspx):

```
var my_object = new {
    Name = string.Empty,
    Telephone = string.Empty,
    ID = string.Empty
};
```